How do you create a VSCode devcontainer with Python and Firefox for selenium testing using pytest and pytest runner?
I am trying to create this container using a dockerfile like so
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox

and a devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "Python 3.10 with Firefox",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "context": ".devcontainer"
    },
    "postCreateCommand": "pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "pamaron.pytest-runner"
            ]
        }
    },
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}

and I get this error:
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'groups')
    [2024-04-09T16:45:11.687Z]     at xu (c:\Users\knueppel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:390:17437)
    [2024-04-09T16:45:11.687Z]     at Y$ (c:\Users\knueppel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:464:2264)
    [2024-04-09T16:45:11.687Z]     at async Fw (c:\Users\knueppel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:464:1831)
    [2024-04-09T16:45:11.687Z]     at async $J (c:\Users\knueppel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:464:608)
    [2024-04-09T16:45:11.687Z]     at async tAA (c:\Users\knueppel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:3660)
    [2024-04-09T16:45:11.687Z]     at async CC (c:\Users\knueppel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:4775)
    [2024-04-09T16:45:11.687Z]     at async NeA (c:\Users\knueppel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:614:11107)
    [2024-04-09T16:45:11.687Z]     at async MeA (c:\Users\knueppel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:614:10848)

I tried changing the DockerFile to an alpine build I saw in a similar post and got the same error.
